# Infinite redirect loop in ASP.NET core while enforcing SSL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I followed the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl) to enforce SSL on my ASP.NET web API, but it always ends up in an infinite loop. What could I be doing wrong? The environment is Windows Server 2016 running in an AWS EC2 VM.

Comment: Use the F12 console network tab to observe what URL's are being redirected to and post here.

Comment: Reverse proxies often terminate ssl so the back end app doesn't know. They should include the original scheme in a header. See UseForwardedHeaders for processing these. See https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/2384

Comment: @Tratcher yup, that seems to be the case. Anyway I decided to redirect at the client to avoid some other issues. Please post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse proxies often terminate ssl so the back end app doesn't know. They should include the original scheme in a header. Use `UseForwardedHeaders` for processing these. Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/2384) on GitHub.

Comment: `app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions { ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.All });` didn't work. What's the fix for this?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1#troubleshoot to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, reverse proxy was on a separate server, so, my asp.net core app was not accepting this proxy because the proxy is no on  `ForwardedHeadersOptions.KnownProxies` and the network is not in `ForwardedHeadersOptions.KnownNetworks` I apply this solution and the inifite loop dissapear:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            options.KnownNetworks.Add(new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:100.64.0.0"), 106));
        });
```

You can also use `options.KnownProxies` and add the ip address of your reverse proxy, In my case I did not add because the reverse proxy is dynamic.

Pay attention to `::ffff:` you need to put this prefix, this is IPv4MappedToIPv6 address more information on https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/2384#issuecomment-387875157

Thanks

Comment: Where did you find the IP address part, i.e: ::ffff:100.64.0.0?

I'm using AWS for hosting but not sure where I find this network part?

Comment: Hi, this is the CIDR of the network,  if you want to give access to any computer in your subnet you need to add the Subnet's IPV4 CIDR, you cant find under VPC service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same redirect issue while integrating a .NET Core app with a Saml2 Idp from behind a loadbalancer/reverse proxy. (https => http)

For me it did the trick to set the Scheme of the request to https (or in my example with the provided proto header of the proxy)

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
});

app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Forwarded-Proto", out StringValues proto))
    {
        context.Request.Scheme = proto;
    }

    return next();
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, when you have `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and the app is behind a reverse proxy you need override `context.Request.Scheme`, seems to be a bug with `app.UseForwardedHeaders`, to make the redirect happens dont forget to set enviromnent variable `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT` to you https port, in my case is the default 443

Comment: We've seen this a few times and it's always been a misconfiguration of UseForwardedHeaders, not a bug. Do not blindly apply X-Forwarded-Proto, it's dangerous.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1#troubleshoot to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which [VictorV's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52189437/1109665) solved. However, I have no control over the network the application is running on. I modified his answer slightly to (I believe) allow requests from any network.

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders =
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        options.KnownNetworks.Add(new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("::ffff:0.0.0.0"), 0));
    });
```

While I'm sure this is less secure, given that I have no control over the network, I don't really see an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Statup.cs` file remove this line:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Comment: This had a downvote but since my app is behind a LoadBalancer that handles the forcing of SSL (and internally forwarding of 443 requests to 80) it is the correct answer, and enabling app.UseHttpsRedirection() results in an endless redirect loop.